# SQL Pull Replication not synchronizing

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

I am trying to establish a pull transactional replication using SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a local DB and a Remote DB, I am using UNC file share for the snapshot.

All are running with no errors, however the publisher on the remote server is showing:

> The initial snapshot for article  is not yet available.

I run the View Snapshot Agent Status and it shows:

> [100%] A snapshot of 1 article(s) was generated.

What is going wrong?

Comment: try starting distributor agent job

Comment: The distributor on the local machine(Since I use pull replication)? How can I start it ?

Comment: yours is a push replication,just start distributor sql agent job

Comment: Hows  it Push ?, the properties show this: 
Distribution Agent Location: Subscriber

Comment: and how to start the distributor sql agent job?

Comment: Via SSMS connect to the Publisher, Under Replication folder go to Local Publications , expand that and then go to the publication , right click and launch the `Replication Monitor`, In replication monitor go to the Subscribers tab and click on the subscribers you are having issues with, see in the details sections what error it is showing? Its more likely to be permissions error by the sound of it.

Comment: @M.Ali no erros at all ..All status are OK, performance is Excellent

Comment: Make sure your `Log Reader Agent` account and `Snap shot agent` account has full control on the `Snapshot share` also make sure both of these accounts are member of `db_owner` role in `Publisher , subscriber and most importantly in Distribution` databases

Comment: Ah in that case connect to the `Subscriber` from SSMS and see the job history for the log reader agent job, you will probably see an error there saying `cannot connect to the distributor` etc

Comment: @M.Ali The job history is running and says "The replication agent has been successfully started. See the Replication Monitor for more information."

Comment: @TheGameiswar I checked the Job and  it is already running

Comment: Why I have this message at the publisher:
The initial snapshot for article <Table_1> is not yet available. ( the database is only one table for testing)